# Why are there multiple ways to pass VAOs to a GLSL program?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Sample code:

```
1. glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
2. glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
3. glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
4. glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
5. glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

So the "0" on lines 4 (first argument) and 5 refer to an arbitrary identifier/location that we have chosen. In GLSL, if we want to refer to this data, we just have to refer to the same ID:

```
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
```

However, in a different example program, I've seen it done differently, with no reference to "layout locations". Instead, we do something like so:

```
1. glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
2. glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
3. glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
4. glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
5. glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, 0, "in_position");
6. glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

We've added an extra step (5) where we seem to bind this attribute pointer to a specific variable in a specific program. And then in our GLSL we just write this instead:

```
in vec3 in_position;
```

With no reference to a location.

If I'm not mistaken, these 2 programs essentially do the exact same thing...so why the difference? What are the pros and cons of each method?

(I've just started learning OpenGL 3.x)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as passing a VAO to a shader. A VAO simply establishes how vertex attributes are pulled from buffer objects for rendering.

The second example doesn't do anything, unless `shaderProgramHandle` has not been linked yet. `glBindAttribLocation` location only works *before* program linking. Once the program has been linked, you can't change where it gets its attributes from.

In any case, your real question is why some people use `glBindAttribLocation(..., 0)` instead of putting `layout(location = X)` in their shaders. The reason is very simple: `layout(location)` syntax is (relatively) new. `glBindAttribLocation` dates back to the very first version of GLSL's OpenGL interface, back in the ARB_vertex_shader extension back in 2003 or so. `layout(location)` comes from the much more recent ARB_explicit_attrib_location, which is only core in GL 3.3 and above. 3.3 only came out in 2010. So naturally more material will talk about the old way.

The "pros and cons" of each are quite obvious. From a purely practical standpoint, `layout(location)`, being new, requires more recent drivers (though it does not require GL 3.3. NVIDIA's 6xxx+ hardware supports ARB_explicit_attrib_location despite being only 2.1). `glBindAttribLocation` works within source code, while `layout(location)` is built into the GLSL shader itself. So if you need to decide which attributes use which indices at runtime, it's a lot harder to do it with `layout(location)` than without it. But if, like most people, you want to control them from the shader, then `layout(location)` is what you need.

Comment: That's weird...because I have a running program that does exactly that. It's not *exactly* as above (it's a C# wrapper) but it definitely links the program before calling glBindAttribLocation. If `layout(location)` is the new way of doing things though, I guess I'll go ahead with that until I hit a road block that convinces me otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: Just because a function does nothing doesn't mean you can't get lucky. If you don't use `layout(location)` or `glBindAttribLocation`, then OpenGL will automatically assign attribute indices as it sees fit.

Comment: Hahaha...you're a genius! I just took out the calls to glBindAttribLocation and it ran exactly the same. Perhaps I should contact the people over at OpenTK because this was the example that came with their library!

Comment: +2 for the comments. Very instructive. Especially "Just because a function does nothing doesn't mean you can't get lucky".

Comment: Quick question about this answer, why do most people want to control them from the shader? It seems to me that if you define them in the shader like that, you'll still need to know the hardcoded locations inside the C code for glVertexAttribPointer. Why not just define it all in one place and be done with it? I'm sure I'm missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: @Verdagon: Because the shader still defines the *name* of the variable. So your GLSL code still needs to conform to the expectations of C code. Namely, that you have a VS input named "position" or whatever. Since that implicit interface between GLSL and C's expectations already exist, it may as well use an location rather than the name. That way, two different shaders can name the variable different things, but use the same location. And the C code won't need to change.